# TextView on GLSurfaceView doesn't update properly

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I've been continuing to play with the glass GDK (and enjoying it) but i've got a new problem that I think (?) is specific to glass and I'm not sure what to do....

I have a immersion running with the contentView set to a framelayout that holds a GLSurfaceView as the back most view and I put a TextView on top.  The GLSurfaceView is (obviously) display some 3D stuff while the front TextView is intended to only hold some status info.

On a phone (running 4.3 or 4.4) it all works perfectly but on glass when I change the text in the text view (view  setText() ) it never 'clears' the background (see below)

[image: image of messed up text view]

I've played around a bit with the obvious sorts of things (trying to manually clear it, setting it with a bunch of 'spaces', manually invalidating the views, etc.) but it stubbornly refuses to clear the background before redrawing the text view (the GLSurfaceView in the back works great however and even if the background surface view draws behind the text it doesn't seem to matter)

I would normally assume this is some ignorance on my part (I'm new to Android dev having spent the last years in iOS development) but as I mentioned it works perfectly.

I suppose it could also be a android 4.0 (vs 4.3+ thing) but I don't have any devices handy to test it with 4.0 (and the simulator doesn't work with openGL 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you should submit a defect or issue here https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list